# Wiring 2 stepper motors sharing wires

Tags: wiring, stepper-motor

*Preface: I'm still new at electronics.*

I have two 4-pin Nema 17 steppers for the Z-axis of my 3D printer. I'm moving the control board outside the enclosure so I need to extend the existing stepper wiring.

Can I join the return (?) from each motor together? e.g. `A_bar` from the two steppers together and `B_bar` from the two steppers together. Then split them up again before connecting it to the 4-pin molex. As in the image below.

Why? So I only need to use one length of 18 AWG wire instead of two 22 AWG wire. Also just for learnings sake.

My reasoning: The signal is sent to `A` separately and `A_bar` is just used for the current to flow back.

Other information: It's a stock Prusa Mk3S. The board is an 8-bit Einsy Rambo.

[image: 2 Steppers]

Comment: https://toms3d.org/2016/07/20/how-to-wire-your-3d-printer/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are referring to in that post. I couldn't find an excerpt where it talks about whether I could do the configuration in the image. I know how to wire the printer like stock. This question is more  about whether 2 steppers can be wired in this configuration for a 3D Printer rather than "How to wire a 3D Printer".

Comment: Did you catch the part about use stranded twisted pair only and wire motion must be along wire direction with large radius?  That means avoid the big area loops in your diagram

Comment: I am using stranded twisted pairs but they are difficult to draw in Photoshop. The diagram was just for wiring references and not to scale. These are for Z-axis on a Cartesian so the wires shouldn't have motion. Not sure how large big area loops are, but the length of wire connecting the `A_bar`s to Molex is 1.2m and the 4 wire out of the motors are only 16cm. However drawing that to scale makes a lot of white space.

Comment: The diagram is improper, and cables do not need to be scaled. But the logic in the diagram must show paired traces from source to load (for EMI reasons) are as important as paired wires to differential source.  As shown it would seem to the reader that it doesn't matter and you have not looked at how drivers work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "return" on a bipolar stepper motor. Each of the windings is connected in a "H-bridge" with both sides being actively driven. Two stepper motors have total four H-bridges and each of the eight wires to the coils is independently driven.

You cannot connect any of these terminals together without compromising the operation or damaging the circuitry.